# knockout, nested foreach

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Let's I have Humans with Cats with Kittens

```
class Master
{  
   String masterName;

   Cat[] cats;  
}
class Cat 
{
   String catName;

   Kitten[] kittens;
}

class Kitten 
{
   String kittenName;
}
```

Now I want show all my Kittens with Cats with Masters in html. I use

```
                    <!-- ko foreach: humans -->
                    <!-- ko foreach: cats -->
                    <!-- ko foreach: kittens -->
<p data-bind="$data.kittenName"></p>
<p data-bind="$parent.catName"></p>
<p data-bind="???????"></p>   <!-- How get master's name? -->
                    <!-- /ko -->
                    <!-- /ko -->
                    <!-- /ko -->
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From the [knockout documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html)

> $parents
>   This is an array representing all of the parent view models:
>
> $parents[0] is the view model from the parent context (i.e., it’s the same as $parent)
>
> $parents[1] is the view model from the grandparent context

You should be able to use `$parents[1]` to access the Master viewmodel.

Answer (score 13):

You can use, `$root` to get to the base object - which in your case will be at the level of `Master`.

```
<!-- ko foreach: humans -->
    <!-- ko foreach: cats -->
        <!-- ko foreach: kittens -->
            <p data-bind="$data.kittenName"></p>
            <p data-bind="$parent.catName"></p>
            <p data-bind="text:console.log($root, $parent, $data)"></p>   <!-- How get master's name? -->
        <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Master isn't root here... Array of Masters is part of another object

Comment: Well, `$root` will get you to the highest level possible. You can then traverse down from there

Comment: @Ilya - just console log to see what level it is that you want

Comment: I cann't get Master name using $root, $parent or $data. Is another way?